# How to split a "full name" column into a separate first and last name column in Google Big Query?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, report

I have a table with a column, full_name that has the full names formatted like this, with no spaces but a comma between:

```
Johnson,Boe
```

How do I query a separation between the two in the simplest way in Google Big Query?

Comment: What does "query a separation between the two" mean?

Comment: within the query, how do I make a separate column, one for first name and one for last name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to split the name, you can use `split()`:

```
split(full_name, ',')[ordinal(1)] as last_name, split(full_name, ',')[ordinal(2)] as first_name
```